# How get rich content from an url (like Discord)?

Tags: embed

How can I get some page informations like title, description, thumbnail, etc. from an url like Discord?

I want do it in php or javascript.

Is it a protocol, an api or anything else?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP, use https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed

> PHP library to get information from any web page (using oembed, opengraph, twitter-cards, scraping the html, etc). It's compatible with any web service (youtube, vimeo, flickr, instagram, etc) and has adapters to some sites like (archive.org, github, facebook, etc).